# Правильний переклад "буйство красок"

Tags: переклад

Допоможіть зробити переклад словосполучення "буйство красок". Я знайшла декілька варіантів перекладу "буйство" - "буяння", "буйство", "буйність".
Словосполучення використовується в такому речені: " Троянда привертає увагу *буйством красок* і відтінків, формою та ароматом квітів."

Який саме краще використати варіант перекладу українською?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Гадаю, тут *краска* може означати колір, тому можна використати **розмаїття барв** або **розмаїття кольорів**.

> **[БА́РВА](http://sum.in.ua/s/barva)**, и, *жін*.
>
> 1. Колір, забарвлення (в 2 знач.). В глибині затоки долі кам'яною стіною ревів водопад, мов живий срібний стовп, граючи до сонця всіма барвами веселки (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 25); Вся вона [гора] вкрита густим-прегустим сосновим лісом, що своєю темною барвою так одрізняється од ясно-золотистого бука (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 139); Їхні обличчя лисніли від поту, кольором зливаючись із барвою сорочок (Володимир Гжицький, Чорне озеро, 1961, 113);  * *Образно*. Заіскрилося всіма барвами народне мистецтво, вдарили ключем з гущі народної таланти (Іван Цюпа, Україна.., 1960, 267).
>
> ...

Отже,  *Троянда привертає увагу розмаїттям барв і відтінків, формою та ароматом квітів.*